# Rails geocoding/Mapbox GL JS "missing CSS declarations for Mapbox GL JS" "_typeof is not defined"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, mapbox-gl

I want to display my MapBox map into may `<div id="map">...` but I'm getting two errors: `>This page appears to be missing CSS declarations for Mapbox GL JS...` and  `>_ReferenceError: _typeof is not defined`

I read a lot of issues about it on the web but still doesn't work :/

**views/layouts/applications.html.erb**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MarryApp</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <!-- <link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.2/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet"  /> -->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
    <%= render 'shared/flashes' %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0">
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
import { initMapbox } from '../plugins/mapbox';

initMapbox();
```

**app/javascript/plugins/mapbox.js**

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

const initMapbox = () => {
  const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

  if (mapElement) { // only build a map if there's a div#map to inject into
    mapboxgl.accessToken = mapElement.dataset.mapboxApiKey;
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10'
    });
  }
  console.log(mapElement.dataset.mapboxApiKey)
};

export { initMapbox };
```